# Permanent solution to error while loading shared libraries

Tags: unix, centos, centos7, graphicsmagick

I got the following error while using Graphicsmagick ( gm convert )

`error while loading shared libraries: libwebp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I use the following command to fix it

`ldconfig /usr/local/lib`

The problem is that the solution isn't permanent , i need to run that command time and again when i get the error?

How can i fix the error permanently?

Comment: Take a look at /etc/ld.so.conf, you can list /usr/local/lib in that file.